# How to extend the height of my Content-Box from the bottom instead of the top

Tags: html, css

I need to extend the content box (white area) closer to the bottom of the page.
When ever I use the `height` or `padding` property, it makes it taller from the top.

[image]

```css
.Content-Box {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 top: 65px;
 padding: 80px;
 height: -40px;
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="Content-Box">
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as negative height. Negative margins and offsets (top, left, bottom, right), yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
padding-bottom: (amount you want)px;
```

Comment: im not sure i understand then, you want more space between "uh oh" and the bottom of the box?

Comment: this answer is exactly what you need @JayBot ... are you sure you are using padding-bottom and not just padding?